# fpdf, fpdi, fpdm & fpdf_merge with multi page pdf - php conflicts

Tags: php, pdf-generation, fpdf

Hoping for some help. I'm trying to use the php below to do 4 things. The 1st long chunk adds a signature image to my sig.pdf template. The 2nd chunk fills form fields in my template3.pdf template.The 3rd chunk should merge both files. And the 4th chunk emails the merged pdf.

1 and 4 by themselves work, and 2 & 4 by themselves work.

With 1, 2, and 4 together the two separate pdfs are created, but the email isn't sent.

3 never works. I get the following error:

```
Fatal error: Uncaught exception 'Exception' with message 'object [1] non trouve' in /home/content/.../html/pdf2/fpdf_merge.php:74 Stack trace: #0 /home/content/.../html/pdf2/fpdf_merge.php(214): FPDF_Merge->error('object [1] non ...') #1 /home/content/.../html/pdf2/fpdf_merge.php(615): FPDF_Merge->getObject(Resource id #23, Array, '1') #2 /home/content/.../html/pdf2/fill.php(79): FPDF_Merge->add('qaf.pdf') #3 {main} thrown in /home/content/.../html/pdf2/fpdf_merge.php on line 74
```

I'm guessing this might be due to my qaf.pdf being 7 pages long, but haven't found any documentation on that.

So my questions are:

1) What can I do to make fpdf_merge.php work with my two documents?

2) Why is my email process not working when I use both the 1st and 2nd processes?

I'm guessing I have things out of order somehow. But I don't know how to troubleshoot that in php.

Thanks for any clues!!

Note: I removed comments (other people's fine work), just to make it easier to read this post. They are retained in my working script.

Cross-posted here: http://www.fpdf.org/phorum/read.php?f=1&i=60395&t=60395

1:

```
$s = new signature; 
$s->use_template_pdf('signed','sig'); 
$s->delete_signature(); 
class signature { 
var $pdf; 
var $hash; 
var $image; 
function __construct(){ 
require('fpdf/fpdf.php'); 
require('fpdi/fpdi.php'); 
$this->make_hash(); 
$this->make_signature(); 
} 
function make_hash(){ 
$this->hash = uniqid(); 
} 
function make_signature(){ 
if(isset($_POST['img'])){ 
$arr = explode(',',$_POST['img']); 
$this->image = "image{$this->hash}.png"; 
if(is_writable(dirname(__FILE__))){ 
file_put_contents($this->image, base64_decode($arr[1])); 
}else{ 
die('<p>The working directory is not writable, abort.</p>'); 
} 
} 
} 
function delete_signature(){ 
if(file_exists($this->image)) @unlink($this->image); 
} 
function use_template_pdf($filename, $template){ 
$this->pdf = new FPDI(); 

$pagecount = $this->pdf->setSourceFile($template.'.pdf'); 
$tplidx = $this->pdf->importPage(1); 
$this->pdf->addPage(); 
$this->pdf->SetXY(90, 260); 
$this->pdf->Write(5,"Signature: "); 
$this->pdf->useTemplate($tplidx, 10, 10); 
$this->pdf->Image($this->image,125,260,-200); 
if(is_writable(dirname(__FILE__))){ 
$this->pdf->Output($filename.'.pdf', 'F'); 
}else{ 
$this->pdf->Output($filename.'.pdf', 'I'); 
} 
$this->pdf = NULL; 
} 
}
```

2:

```
require('fpdm/fpdm.php'); 
$fields = array( 
'cascade' => $_POST['_fid_6'], 
'structuretype' => $_POST['_fid_7'], 
'marketmanager' => $_POST['_fid_8'], 
); 
$pdf = new FPDM('template3.pdf'); 
$pdf->Load($fields, false); 
$pdf->Merge(); 
$pdf->Output('qaf.pdf', 'F');
```

3:

```
require('fpdf_merge.php'); 
$merge = new FPDF_Merge(); 
$merge->add('qaf.pdf'); 
$merge->add('signed.pdf'); 
$merge->output('qaf-final.pdf', 'F');
```

4:

```
$to = $_POST['_fid_6']; 
$from = "qaf@me.com"; 
$subject = "Your QAF"; 
$separator = md5(time()); 
$eol = PHP_EOL; 
$filename = "qaf-final.pdf"; 
$pdfdoc = $pdf->Output("", "S"); 
$attachment = chunk_split(base64_encode($pdfdoc)); 
$headers = "From: ".$from.$eol; 
$headers .= "MIME-Version: 1.0".$eol; 
$headers .= "Content-Type: multipart/mixed; boundary=\"".$separator."\""; 
$body = "--".$separator.$eol; 
$body .= "Content-Transfer-Encoding: 7bit".$eol.$eol; 
$body .= "Here is your QAF.".$eol; 
$body .= "--".$separator.$eol; 
$body .= "Content-Type: application/octet-stream; name=\"".$filename."\"".$eol; 
$body .= "Content-Transfer-Encoding: base64".$eol; 
$body .= "Content-Disposition: attachment".$eol.$eol; 
$body .= $attachment.$eol; 
$body .= "--".$separator."--"; 
mail($to, $subject, $body, $headers);
```

Comment: I'm not sure if it'll help with the email thing, but you should totally look into PHPMailer or SwiftMailer to send that attached file.  Rolling your own MIME is a real pain.

Comment: Have gotten anywhere with this yet? I would also like to see the solution.